# Can not find “visible-xs-block” source code in Bootstrap.css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap. 
In my project, "visible-xs-block" is a class name. But I can not find “visible-xs-block” source code in Bootstrap.css file

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Where to find the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
.visible-xs-block, .visible-xs-inline, .visible-xs-inline-block {
    display: none!important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-xs-block {
      display: block!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the source code of "visible-xs-block"? I open my  `bootstrap.css` file, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: press `Ctrl+Shift+I` in your browser while your page is open and inspect page elements in "Inspector" window.

Answer (score 1):

`.visible-xs-block` is an old class from bootstrap 3. It is not present anymore in bootstrap 4. Please see the [migration hints](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've find it with your help.

Comment: Then please mark it as answered for other users to see (appears green in the overview).